Error al intentar usar FFMPEG para añadir metadatos al video
Estoy tratando de añadir metadatos a un video pero siempre da error: "ReferenceError: FFmpeg is not defined" por más que cambie de librería. qué estoy haciendo mal?


(async () => {
            const { createFFmpeg, fetchFile } = FFmpeg;
            const ffmpeg = createFFmpeg({ log: true });
            await ffmpeg.load();

            const videoInput = document.getElementById('videoInput');
            const titleInput = document.getElementById('title');
            const descriptionInput = document.getElementById('description');
            const processButton = document.getElementById('process');
            const outputVideo = document.getElementById('output');

            processButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
                const file = videoInput.files[0];
                const title = titleInput.value;
                const description = descriptionInput.value;

                if (file) {
                    const arrayBuffer = await file.arrayBuffer();
                    ffmpeg.FS('writeFile', 'input.mp4', new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer));

                    await ffmpeg.run(
                        '-i', 'input.mp4',
                        '-metadata', `title=${title}`,
                        '-metadata', `description=${description}`,
                        'output.mp4'
                    );

                    const outputData = ffmpeg.FS('readFile', 'output.mp4');
                    const outputBlob = new Blob([outputData.buffer], { type: 'video/mp4' });
                    outputVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(outputBlob);
                }
            });
        })();
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ffmpeg/ffmpeg@latest"></script>

<h1>Adjuntar Metadatos al Video</h1>
    <input type="file" id="videoInput" accept="video/*">
    <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Título">
    <textarea id="description" placeholder="Descripción"></textarea>
    <button id="process">Procesar Video</button>
    <video id="output" controls></video>




Te recomiendo revisar Migrating from 0.11.x to 0.12+
